# d3.js return value of function always undefined

Tags: d3.js

I am calling a function from my index.html file. The function is defined in a javascript file which i have referred to in the html. However the return value is always undefined. When i debug i  could see the value in the return string.

Follwing is the code in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readQueryStringparam(name) 
    {

        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
        var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
        if (results == null)
        return "";
        else
        return results[1];
    } 


function getDiDataUrlPrefix() 
{

             diDataUrlPrefix = diGlobal.instanceInfo.getDiDataUrlPrefix();
            //alert(diDataUrlPrefix);   
            sbu = readQueryStringparam('sbu');
            appid = readQueryStringparam('appid');


            if (sbu.length > 0) 
            {
                sbu = sbu.trim();
                CreateChart(diDataUrlPrefix,sbu,0,appid);
            }
            else if (appid.length > 0)
                {

                    sbu = GetSBUForApplication(appid);
                    CreateChart(diDataUrlPrefix,0,0,appid);
                }
}

 </script>
```

I get the value for the parameters supplied in the url as well as diDataUrlPrefix.

Following is the code in the javascript file:

```
function GetSBUForApplication(appid)
{
    setTimeout(function() { }, 10000);
    var string;
    var file = diDataUrlPrefix + "/oss/csvs/Consolidated_RAG.csv";

    d3.text(file, function(datasetText) 
        {

            parsedCSVapp = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);


            if (appid >0)
            {
                    parsedCSVapp = parsedCSVapp.filter(function(row)
                    {
                        //alert(parsedCSVapp);
                        return row[0] == appid



                    })//parsed fileter ends here

                returnstring = parsedCSVapp[0][4];



            }

        })



    return returnstring;

}
```

However the value of sbu is always undefined.However i can see the values in parsedCSVapp.  The csv file looks like this:

Application_Id,Application Name,Status,Name,Business Unit
200039,DEALING,RED,Marc Begun,Financial&Risk
200070,NGTX,RED,Marc Begun,Financial&Risk
200097,WORLD-CHECK,RED,Graham Fisher,Financial&Risk
200009,BOARDLINK,RED,Jennifer Simon,Financial&Risk
200088,THOMSON ONE,RED,Jonathan Weinberg,Financial&Risk
200037,DATASTREAM,RED,Ian Brocklehurst,Financial&Risk
200044,EIKON,RED,Olivier Martin,Financial&Risk
200011,COLLABORATION,RED,Frank Tarsillo,Financial&Risk

Comment: `d3.text` is an asynchronous callback. The function you specify as an argument is executed when the call returns, while the code after it is executed immediately, i.e. when `returnstring` is not defined yet.

Comment: ok... so can i replace the d3.text with d3.csv. Will it solve this? How can this be resolved in this scenario

Comment: You can't -- all of these are asynchronous. You need to run all the code you want to run with the return value in the callback function.

Comment: when you say callback function, is it the d3.text function? Could you kindly elaborate

Comment: `d3.text` (and `d3.csv`, `d3.json` and similar) are asynchronous calls. The second argument to those functions is a function that gets executed when the call returns -- the callback. This function will not be executed at the same time as you run `d3.text`, but later. You cannot determine at what time exactly it will be run.

Comment: thanks a lot lars. I changed the code and it is working fine. Can you answer this query so that i can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.text` (and `d3.csv`, `d3.json` and similar) make asynchronous calls. That is, when you run the code, the call is made and execution resumes without waiting for the call to return.
The second argument to those functions is a function that gets executed when the call returns -- the callback.

This function will not be executed at the same time as you run `d3.text`, but later. You cannot determine at what time exactly it will be run. Any code that you want to call as a result of one of those calls needs to be run as part of the callback function, or called from there.